# Where on the server are the svn folders I checked in?

Tags: svn, fsfs

Trying to understand something.  I created a d:\svn\repository on my server.  I committed folders but when I go back to d:\svn\repository I do not see them.  Are they all in a database?  Will all my repositories go in that main folder and svn tracks them?  What if I have two projects?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subversion doesn't store the logical folders in the same structure on the server, it tracks everything in an file of the deltas in a "database". This database is specific to Subversion. Everything committed to that repository goes in that file. You won't find your logical structure on the server, it just doesn't work that way.

From [FSFS](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch05.html#svn-ch-5-sect-1.3.2)

> In mid-2004, a second type of
>   repository storage system came into
>   being: one which doesn't use a
>   database at all. An FSFS repository
>   stores a revision tree in a single
>   file, and so all of a repository's
>   revisions can be found in a single
>   subdirectory full of numbered files.
>   Transactions are created in separate
>   subdirectories. When complete, a
>   single transaction file is created and
>   moved to the revisions directory, thus
>   guaranteeing that commits are atomic.
>   And because a revision file is
>   permanent and unchanging, the
>   repository also can be backed up while
>   “hot”, just like a Berkeley DB
>   repository.
>
> The revision-file format represents a
>   revision's directory structure, file
>   contents, and deltas against files in
>   other revision trees. Unlike a
>   Berkeley DB database, this storage
>   format is portable across different
>   operating systems and isn't sensitive
>   to CPU architecture. Because there's
>   no journaling or shared-memory files
>   being used, the repository can be
>   safely accessed over a network
>   filesystem and examined in a read-only
>   environment. The lack of database
>   overhead also means that the overall
>   repository size is a bit smaller.
>
> FSFS has different performance
>   characteristics too. When committing a
>   directory with a huge number of files,
>   FSFS uses an O(N) algorithm to append
>   entries, while Berkeley DB uses an
>   O(N^2) algorithm to rewrite the whole
>   directory. On the other hand, FSFS
>   writes the latest version of a file as
>   a delta against an earlier version,
>   which means that checking out the
>   latest tree is a bit slower than
>   fetching the fulltexts stored in a
>   Berkeley DB HEAD revision. FSFS also
>   has a longer delay when finalizing a
>   commit, which could in extreme cases
>   cause clients to time-out when waiting
>   for a response.
>
> The most important distinction,
>   however, is FSFS's inability to be
>   “wedged” when something goes wrong. If
>   a process using a Berkeley DB database
>   runs into a permissions problem or
>   suddenly crashes, the database is left
>   unusable until an administrator
>   recovers it. If the same scenarios
>   happen to a process using an FSFS
>   repository, the repository isn't
>   affected at all. At worst, some
>   transaction data is left behind.